# How to open workbook with dynamic title?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open workbook utilizing VBA macro with date in the title. The file path will be as follows "Cash 200819"

I have tried and failed as I think I am not getting my syntax right, any help will be appreciated.

```
Dim WB3 As Workbook, WB4 As Workbook
Dim ws3 As Worksheet, ws4 As Worksheet
Set WB3 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws3 = WB3.Sheets("Cash")
Set WB4 = Workbooks.Open("\\prod\groupshares\PORTFOLIO MANAGEMENT\cash "today() & ".xlsx")
```

I am trying to open and copy the entire first page of the workbook into cash tab in my active spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `&` in your lt line of code... depending on the formatting/local settings of your MS Office installation, the date will also not appear correctly formatted as a string, so i included `CSTR()`. Last but not least, `Today()` is a workbook function, in VBA you can get the date by using `DATE`.

```
Set WB4 = Workbooks.Open("\\prod\groupshares\PORTFOLIO MANAGEMENT\cash " & Cstr(Date) & ".xlsx)
```

To get the format you specified for the date (200819 --> 20. Aug 2019) you could use this...

```
format(cstr(date),"dd")&cstr(format(date,"mm"))&right(cstr(year(date)),2)
```

Everything put together would be...

```
Set WB4 = Workbooks.Open("\\prod\groupshares\PORTFOLIO MANAGEMENT\cash " & _ 
    format(cstr(date),"dd")&cstr(format(date,"mm"))& _ 
    right(cstr(year(date)),2) & ".xlsx)
```

Comment: that unfortunately does not work for me, the below works for me now, anyone know how i will be able to not specifically define the year?    `Dim bkdte As String, mnth As String, dte As String

    dte = Now()
    mnth = Month(dte)
    dte = Day(dte)
    
    bkdte = dte & "" & mnth & "2019"
    
    Set WB3 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws3 = WB3.Sheets("Cash")
    Set WB4 = Workbooks.Open("\\prod\groupshares\PORTFOLIO MANAGEMENT\cash " & bkdte & ".xlsx")`

Comment: How not to specifically define the date is included in my answer. Look at the last part.

Comment: thanks! it works, i ran into another problem, how do i copy just the first page of the opened workbook into the tab? can i just set ws4 = sheet1     `ws4.Activate
    
            Last_Row4 = ws4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            ws4.Range("A1:Z" & Last_Row4).Copy ws3.Range("A1")`

Comment: You might want to post that as another question... however, here a quick answer of how to copy any worksheet: `activesheet.copy` ... using the `.copy` command on any worksheet object immediately creates a new sheet. Another method could be `.usedrange.copy` which copies the used range of a worksheet... then you paste it where ever you wish.